# Block Gmail from stealing focus with user script

Tags: safari, gmail, focus, userscripts, ninjakit

I'm trying to stop Gmail from stealing focus using a user script. I'm using NinjaKit on safari. So far I have

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name GMAIL           
// @namespace      https://mail.google.com
// @include        https://mail.google.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
//alert("It's working");
window.focus = function(){};
```

But still the window manages to steal focus.

I can see that it's indeed activating the userscript if I comment out the alert line: the alert pops up (many times).

Test this by opening `mail.google.com/` and then quickly switching to a new tab. Gmail loads in the background but then switches back to focus, stealing it from the other tab.

Comment: If I change the include to be //@include * then I catch all websites and gmail still steals focus. So is it not using window.focus to do this? How else can it steal focus?

Comment: Use `unsafeWindow.focus = function(){};`, except NinjaKit looks like it might not support `@run-at document-start`.

Comment: PS:  Not sure about Safari, but the `alert()` will cause focus to switch back on some browsers.

Comment: No go with <code>unsafeWindow.focus = function(){};</code> either. (The alert was just for a test, it still steals the focus without the alert) (see edited post)

Comment: Yeah, you need `@run-at document-start` too. Ninjakit doesn't support it, at a quick glance.

Comment: Know of an alternative for Safari that does/might?

Comment: No.  I'm not a Safari user/expert.  It looks like you may be [out of luck with Safari](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Cross-browser_userscripting#Safari).